# Constructor Overriding in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overriding

Can we override a constructor of super class in sub class of the same class.
If yes, how?
If no, why?

```
class Super{}
class Sub extends Super
{
    //write code, if yes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you cannot *override* the `constructor` of the `Super` class. **JVM** will definitely call the *super class constructor* while creating the *child class instance*. So, whenever you *create* a *subclass instance*, it will invoke the *baseclass constructor* and then *continue* with the *subclass constructor statements*. `Constructors` are **not** `Methods` that can be *overriden*

Answer (score 1):

> Can we override a constructor of super class in sub class of the same class?

No.

With inheritance you can get/obtain instance members only. Constructor is not a member of class. Jvm treats it specially to construct an object . You can check that by seeing byte code instructions.

By `ovveriding`, what you acheive ??  A constructor must construct the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors cannot be overridden. The concept of constructor is to create an instance of class, and that behavior belongs to that class only and cannot be overidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of override the constructor. You cannot actually override one, but you can achieve some of the same results.

When you specify a constructor in the child class you can build that however you like. That constructor can then choose which `super()` constructor gets called.

So you can block some child constructors, you can modify the parameters to them, etc. The only limitation is that at least one super constructor **must** be called.

```
A {  A(int i) {} A(String b) }

B extends A { B(int i) { super(i); doStuff() } }

C extends A { C(String b) { super(Integer.parseInt(b)) } }
```

So we have a class `A` with two constructors.

Class `B` on the other hand has no `String` constructor, and does extra stuff after the super constructor happens.

Class `C` has no int constructor - but when you call the `String` constructor in `C` it actually goes to the `int` constructor in `A`.

Comment: It's not about calling, OP wants to ovveride it. I may wrong, please cross check once.

Comment: The constructor is only called when you construct the class. You cannot completely replace the behaviour of the super constructors (as one has to be called) - but you can modify the behaviour by restricting which super constructors can be called, and how they are called, and what else happens when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an object, any parent constructors are called before the constructor specific to that object. You cannot change this behaviour.

**However, it *is* possible**, with some trickery, **to create an object without invoking *any* constructors**. After which, of course, you can perform any initialisation that you need.

You can use [objenesis](http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/) to create the object for you. It's pretty low-level stuff; operating at the byte-code level.

Note that you can't do this using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

overiding defines same name with parameter type, constructor overriding defins same named constructor in parent as well as in child which defines same named parent and child class which can't be possible ..so no we can not do constructor overriding hence we can do constructor overloading.